# What does it take to update kernel from 3.x to 5.X on qualcomm fsm99XX small cells platform

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

As of now qualcomm fsm99xx is on 3.10.84. 3.10.84 is given by qualcomm after a lot of extensive changes. we are trying to update it to 5.10 without support of qualcomm (as they don't support any more). We are encountering lots of driver issues as we tried port old msm drivers on to latest 5.10 kernel.

For e.g.

```
error: CPU_TASKS_FROZEN’ undeclared (first use in this function);
error: implicit declaration of function ‘register_cpu_notifier’
```

I see that these key words were there in 3.10.84 and were not there in latest 5.X.
So how to go about to understand these kernel changes and do that same for driver code so as not to use those who are no longer there in latest 5.X kernel?

Comment: Trying to jump 20 releases'/7 years' worth of changes will need a significant rework of the code that will need real kernel expertise that I think only a handful of people here have. AFAIK only the Fairphone people (at least in the area of general-use hardware) have done upgrades without Qualcomm support. You might want to reach and collaborate with them, but I don't think they use this module.